# How do I create a horizontal scrolling component with HTML, CSS, and React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, horizontal-scrolling

I am making a horizontal scrolling component like instagram stories. But I could not figure out how to do it?
Here is what i am trying to do:

```css
.scroller{
  height: 125px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.itemContainer{
  display: flex;
}
.item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
   <div class="itemContainer">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using flexbox properties but that could not help. I also tried using block and inline-block elements to make items overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the flex items [`flex-shrink: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) so their width won't collapse due to insufficient container space.

```css
.scroller{
  height: 125px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.itemContainer{
  display: flex;
}
.item{
  flex-shrink: 0; /*added*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
   <div class="itemContainer">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```